# Ajax call getting CORS errors/conflicts

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, ajaxaddtocart, cors

What i'm trying to do is as follows, we have different external content pages that have one or more of our products and need a simple "add to cart" button.

To accomplish this i want to use a ajax call that talks to the magento api with json following the dev site of magento:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-add-items.html

Before i can add a product i need to create a cart (Quote id). So first i need to create a guest-cart and then add the products to cart, i have been able to do this in Postman but when i try this in a simple html page i'm getting errors...

I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load https:///rest/V1/guest-carts: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

My code is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://<domain>/rest/V1/guest-carts",
            "method": "POST",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "headers": {
                // "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        }

        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                alert("Awesome, it worked!");
            })
            .fail(function( status, errorThrown ) {
                alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
                console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                console.log( "Status: " + status );
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

I found that CORS was giving issues with chrome and the server because it sends first a method OPTIONS to check if the server allows the method POST. So i added the code from this site: https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640 to the nginx config to allow OPTIONS, GET and POST. When i check in chrome at the Network tab i see that OPTIONS gives status code 204 back but the POST gets a 404 status code.

This is the part where i'm running out of options since i don't know what to do next. Hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I noticed something new, when i add the CORS OPTIONS i'm unable to visit the swagger (API) page. Also tried it with Postman and getting a 404. Weird thing is that i do get a status 200 when i use the code/javascript above.

I finally found what was the issue. In the nginx config file i used location /rest that doesn't work. But i shouldnt give CORS acces to whole of root. Any idea's guys?